# Vercel: Cannot import other functions with Python Serverless API

Tags: python, next.js, vercel

I am trying to import helper functions into my Serverless Flask Api but am unable to do so with Vercel using the `vercel dev` command.

My folder structure is:

```
api
  _utils/
    common.py
  app.py
```

However, when I try to import my helper function into my app.py file I get an error saying module cannot be found.

Below is sample code from my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from _utils.common import helper_function
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: I replicated your problem and presented the same problem. the solution was to change the _utils folder to another name and change the import.

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães I tried renaming it and that did not work. Just so that we are on the sea page this is using vercel, so the startup command is  'vercel dev'. Not the usual python app.py command

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães I upgraded my vercel version and it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Kalimantan If it worked, can you provide and accepted answer along with a **working example**? There's a similar question here: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4717

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I moved my _utils file to the root of my project and now in my api/index.py I import as follows

`from _utils.common import helper_function`

My vercel.json file looks like:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/index.py"
    }
  ]
}
```